# Allow irc connection to socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mirc

Have now a node.js & socket.io real time chat, now i want to allow users who want to join with mIRC to connect to my chatbox.

I tried allready to join with mirc by doing /server mydom.ch 5558 but it couldnt connect.

Does anyone know how to allow mirc connections ?

Answer (score 1):

Your server needs to implement the IRC protocol. It's not trivial.

This is **[RFC 2812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812)** which defines how both the server and client in the IRC protocol needs to behave. Your server needs to do its part.